# How can I enable scrolling for Modal in Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Is it possible to create a Modal that behaves similar to Dialog with scroll set to 'paper'?  I currently have a lot of text to display in the Modal but it ends up going beyond the size of the browser window and there is no option to scroll.

Answer (score 2):

It would be largely depending on the actual use case, but in general the content container in `Modal` can be manually styled with a set `maxHeight` and `overflowY: auto`, to have a vertically scrolling container similar to a `Dialog` set with `scroll="paper"`.

Example live on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pnfcer?file=src/App.js)

```
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Modal from "@mui/material/Modal";
import Fade from "@mui/material/Fade";
import Backdrop from "@mui/material/Backdrop";

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleOpen} variant="contained">
        Open modal
      </Button>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        closeAfterTransition
        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
        BackdropProps={{
          timeout: 500,
        }}
      >
        <Fade in={open}>
          <Box
            sx={{
              position: "absolute",
              top: "50%",
              left: "50%",
              transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
              width: 400,
              bgcolor: "background.paper",
              border: "3px solid #000",
              borderRadius: "10px",
              boxShadow: 24,
              py: 4,
            }}
          >
            <Typography variant="h6" component="h2" sx={{ px: 4 }}>
              Lorem ipsum
            </Typography>
            <Typography
              component="div"
              //  Content box styled to scroll when overflowing
              sx={{ px: 4, mt: 2, maxHeight: "50vh", overflowY: "auto" }}
            >
              Long text content here
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </Fade>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```